# Cannot set NSUserDefault ToggleSwitch Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

I have a form within my IPad app that allows the user to configure the application settings (they can also change these settings from the IPad settings app). I have the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:externalAddress forKey:@"firstString_preference"];
[defaults setValue:internalAddress forKey:@"secondString_perference"];
[defaults setValue:isConnectedToDemoString forKey:@"firstToggle_preference"];
[defaults setValue:isConnectedToInternal forKey:@"secondToggle_preference"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The firstString_preference and secondString_perference are Textfields in the settings bundle and they save to the settings without issue. My problem is the firstToggle_preference and secondToggle_preference are toggle switches in the settings bundle and I cannot seem to set these at all. They always seem to be set to no.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Should i be using a different method for setting Toggle Switch default values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What type are `isConnectedToDemoString` and `isConnectedToInternal`. Unless those are `NSNumber`s, you should use `setBool:forKey:`.

Also, while `setValue:forKey:` works for storing object types to the user defaults, your code would be clearer if you used the `NSUserDefaults`-native `setObject:forKey:` method.